# Como ejecutar un WebDriver desde otro lugar?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

les cuento, soy programador en Python y me dedico principalmente a hacer modelos de Machine Learning y Web Scraping. Cuando hago códigos con WebScraping que contienen Webdriver, al vender el código a otra persona, esta persona necesita ejecutar el código y observar todo el proceso del WebDriver en su propia computadora.
Para evitar esto, estuve viendo que existe la implementación de Servidores.
Mi pregunta es: Hay actualmente servidores gratuitos que pueda usar para alojar el Webdriver y que se ejecute en este servidor? En caso de que no haya gratuitos, hay alguno que tenga pago único(pagar una sola vez) y que no sea pago mensual? Agradecería que me compartieran cualquier información y servidores que sirvan para mi caso, Muchas Gracias